# AttributeError: 'Functional' object has no attribute 'epochs'

Tags: python, tensorflow, matplotlib, keras, scikit-learn

I am getting this attribute error when I want to plot multiple accuracy curves into one graph. I am using functional methods for creating the model. The problem appeared when I tried to use transfer learning techniques but no problem while building a custom CNN model.

Here is my error:

```
<ipython-input-98-bc468a9a0ab2> in <module>()
----> 1 plot_performance_acc(model_06, model_07, model_08, model_09, model_10)

<ipython-input-97-021c960ff924> in plot_performance_acc(hist, hist_one, hist_two, hist_three, hist_four)
      3 
      4     hist_00 = hist.history
----> 5     epochs_00 = hist.epoch
      6 
      7     hist_01 = hist_one.history

AttributeError: 'Functional' object has no attribute 'epoch'
```

My code starts here,

```
def get_model():
    
    base_model = tf.keras.applications.EfficientNetB0(include_top=False, weights = 'imagenet')
    base_model.trainable = False
    inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(256, 256, 3), name="input_layer")
    x = base_model(inputs)
    x = tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D(name="global_average_pooling_layer")(x)
    outputs = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation="sigmoid", name="output_layer")(x)
    model = tf.keras.Model(inputs, outputs)

    return model
```

Plot function:

```
def plot_performance_acc(hist, hist_one, hist_two, hist_three, hist_four):
    plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (20, 10)
    
    hist_00 = hist.history
    epochs_00 = hist.epoch
    
    hist_01 = hist_one.history
    epochs_01 = hist_one.epoch
    
    hist_02 = hist_two.history
    epochs_02 = hist_two.epoch
    
    hist_03 = hist_three.history
    epochs_03 = hist_three.epoch
    
    hist_04 = hist_four.history
    epochs_04 = hist_four.epoch
    
    plt.subplot(1, 2, 1) # row 1, col 2 index 1
    plt.plot(epochs_00, hist_00['accuracy'], label='Learning Rate: 0.1')
    plt.plot(epochs_01, hist_01['accuracy'], label='Learning Rate: 0.01')
    plt.plot(epochs_02, hist_02['accuracy'], label='Learning Rate: 0.001')
    plt.plot(epochs_03, hist_03['accuracy'], label='Learning Rate: 0.0001')
    plt.plot(epochs_04, hist_04['accuracy'], label='Learning Rate: 0.00001')
    
    plt.xlabel('Epochs')
    plt.ylabel('Accuracy')
    # plt.ylim([-0.001, 2.0])
    plt.title('Training accuracy with Adam optimizer')
    plt.legend(loc = 'lower right')
    
    plt.subplot(1, 2, 2) # row 1, col 2 index 1
    plt.plot(epochs_00, hist_00['val_accuracy'], label='Learning Rate: 0.1')
    plt.plot(epochs_01, hist_01['val_accuracy'], label='Learning Rate: 0.01')
    plt.plot(epochs_02, hist_02['val_accuracy'], label='Learning Rate: 0.001')
    plt.plot(epochs_03, hist_03['val_accuracy'], label='Learning Rate: 0.0001')
    plt.plot(epochs_04, hist_04['val_accuracy'], label='Learning Rate: 0.00001')
    
    
    plt.xlabel('Epochs')
    plt.ylabel('Accuracy')
    # plt.ylim([-0.001, 0.9])
    plt.title('Validation accuracy with Adam optimizer')
    plt.legend(loc = 'lower right')

    plt.tight_layout(2)
    fig1 = plt.gcf()
    plt.show()
    plt.draw()
    fig1.savefig('acc.png', dpi=50)
```

Comment: epoch and epochs are different. Are you sure this is not just a typo?

Comment: You are passing a model where a History object is expected

Comment: I understand where I made a mistake. Rather than passing history as a parameter, I mistakenly pass model names that don't have the attribute epochs. Thanks, @Dr.Snoopy, and @user202729

`plot_performance_acc(history_06, history_07, history_08, history_09, history_10)` 

instead of 
`plot_performance_acc(model_06, model_07, model_08, model_09, model_10)`

Answer (score 0):

The mistake was proving the wrong parameters in the plotting function. For plotting, the history object provides attributes like epochs.

current:

*plot_performance_acc(history_06, history_07, history_08, history_09, history_10)*

instead of

*plot_performance_acc(model_06, model_07, model_08, model_09, model_10)*

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).